# How do you decide whether to let a student asking for a (professor-level) advisor to be apart of their senior/junior undergraduate thesis?

Tags: thesis, advisor, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

What are your expectations for a student asking for an advisor for a senior/junior undergraduate thesis and what do students need to have to write a approvable junior/senior thesis?

Is there some minimum kind of research proposal they should submit or a rubric you keep in your hand to evaluate their proposals to sift out students who don't have their ideas planned out, and what students do?

Do you try an experimental approach where you agree to everyone who asks you to be an advisor, and let the ones who can't swim, sink, and let the ones can can swim, swim or do you do prediction and tell them yes or no?

When should you deflect/defer their idea or how do you measure/predict its worth?

In what circumstances should you refuse to advise them on a thesis, and tell them to downgrade their project to a collaborative paper instead where they aren't first-author? When do you tell them this idea, it's so cliche-overused, you should just apply for jobs telling people you have this idea, and it's better off in a corporate world?
When do you tell them this isn't good enough idea to write a thesis, and you should just write something that's no-name and so bad-it belongs at most in ArXiv, and they submit it on your own to ArXiv without anyone's input?

In what cases do you tell them a undergraduate thesis is too bad for them, and they should go straight into a PhD and find a good advisor to have this idea and become a published paper/PhD dissertation because they're so good, because you don't have the resources/time/knowledge to help them develop the idea, so they can go to a PhD without a senior thesis?

How much of an outline or draft does the student need to write themselves before you can help?

Does this have to be hands-on, or is the idea mostly theirs?

Does the student have to pick someone who writes at least one research paper a year/is an active researcher? Do professors who haven't written a paper or published in 4-5 years are too rusty to advise or advised only 2 papers in 10 years of teaching/working ill-equipped to do this?

Some people may say the idea has to be original, but I've seen approved senior/junior thesis on topics that are not original. I am not against baseball or game theory, but as an example...

I've seen according to my limited knowledge students finishing thesis with a main idea on a topic that aren't original, and they've succeeded. For example, baseball +Nash's game theory analysis via simulated data or real data. Baseball analytics isn't new, and neither is Nash the mathematician's theory.

Comment: Too many questions. The standard we look for is one per post.

Comment: What worries me about this question as well is that the expectation for undergraduate theses is not publication quality nor publication level novelty. I've seen some on decent ideas and I've seen some with some extremely nicely executed results which a professional might consider a strong preliminary investigation.

Comment: Agree with Buffy. Your "main question" seems to be, how to choose which students to advise on their undergraduate thesis. This is an interesting question. I recommend you [edit] your post to focus on that question only. After the answers come in, if the other questions still remain, you can make another post.

Comment: I think this is unanswerable. Every professor, and every institution, are going to have different expectations.  And polling for what various individuals choose to do is off topic.

Comment: Do you mean "apart of" (separated from) or "a part of" (included in)?

Answer (score 2):

An undergraduate thesis project isn't expected to produce original, publishable research. Rather, most undergraduate theses require students to demonstrate knowledge in their field and proficiency in the skills they will eventually use for research. While it's possible to fail a senior project due to missed deadlines, poor work, etc., research novelty typically isn't a requirement.

To use one of your examples, undergraduate students working with game theory analysis aren't trying to expand on the field. They're trying to show that they understand game theory, know how to work with simulated data, can complete a semi-independent project, and can write a short paper or presentation on their results.

Requirements for an undergraduate thesis will of course vary between region and institution. I am answering based on my experiences with STEM programs in the United States.

Comment: What's good about those who do one compared to those who don't write one?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The good of doing a senior thesis is getting an experience of working on a months-long project with an advisor and, presumably, fulfilling your program's requirement to do a senior thesis.